# 403 Error on Google Cloud DNS REST Api

Tags: rest, dns, google-cloud-platform

I am using the Google Cloud DNS REST API (with Ruby REST Client) and I am receiving a 403 error using my google service account.  This works correctly when I use the cloud console admin under my personal admin account.

My service account has "owner" permissions so I would think that I should not receive a 403 error.

```
{"response":"{
"error  ": {     "errors  ": 
 [    {       "domain":   "global  ",
   "reason  ":   "forbidden  ",
   "message  ":   "Forbidden  "    }   ],
 "code  ": 403,
"message ":   "Forbidden  "   }
```

Unfortunately this error does not shed any light on why I am receiving a 403.

Comment: Almost certainly user error with credentials. Can you validate the credentials at https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/dns/dns/v1/?

Comment: I am not sure how to validate my service account credentials in that UI?  I've successfully validated my personal credentials and it works fine.  

Agree that it is likely some credential error.  Just not quite sure how to fix.   I am able to launch Google Cloud instances using the same credentials just fine for example.

Comment: Apologies, it looks like you can't easily use the API Explorer with service account credentials. Did you grant the relevant IAM roles to the service account?See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances.

Comment: Yes I have granted owner to the service account.

```
gcloud iam service-accounts get-iam-policy redacted@redacted.iam.gserviceaccount.com

bindings:
- members:
  - serviceAccount:redacted@redacted.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/editor
- members:
  - serviceAccount:redacted@redacted.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/iam.serviceAccountActor
- members:
  - serviceAccount:redacted@redacted.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/owner ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 "Owner" permissions that are available in Google Cloud IAM console.

The correct one is accessed by clicking:

IAM & Admin -> IAM -> [Your Service Account] -> (Roles Dropdown) -> Owner (Then Click Save)

The one that didn't help for me was at:

IAM & Admin -> Service Accounts -> [Your Service Account] -> Permissions -> Add Member -> (Type in service account) -> (Select Owner Role)

I think that second one doesn't work?  Or doesn't do anything.

Comment: The latter does not assign roles to the service account. Instead it grants permissions to a third party so that they can access the service account (as an owner, editor, viewer or service account actor).